# Using external variables inside expressions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to get access to the AlertDialog instance, but in Kotlin I don't have access. Why?

```
fun showDialog(){
    val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.get_info) { dialogInterface, i ->
            alertDialog //here is the error
        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: At this point there is no instance. you are midway through building the alertDialog and don't actually get a value for it until you call 'build()' somewhere down at the bottom at the end of the builder

Comment: If you trying run your `Alert` in `main` fun this will make some  `Toolkit` and `PlatformImpl` initialization issues, And I don't tell it's impossible but just for make sense use special libs like `TornadoFx` and that last make those thing so easy use.